# openocd on windows invalid command "jtag" with phytec lpc3250 target using an olimex arm-usb-ocd-h jtag dongle

Tags: windows, debugging, arm, jtag, openocd

Can someone help me understand an "invalid command name" error with openocd? Some details:

- openocd 0.7.0 windows binary
- olimex arm-usb-ocd-h dongle
- lpc3250 phytec based board

Steps I've done:

1. Downloaded file "openocd-0.7.0.7z" from http://www.freddiechopin.info/en/download/category/4-openocd
2. Extracted it to "c:\oocd7\".
3. Followed the instruction in "c:\oocd7\drivers\libusb-1.0drivers.txt" to run "sadig.exe" to install the "libusb-win32" drivers for the following three usb devices.
4. Then got the error detailed below.

Command and Error Screenshot:

```
c:\oocd7>c:\oocd7\bin-x64\openocd-x64-0.7.0.exe -f board\phytec_lpc3250.cfg -f interface\olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.7.0 (2013-05-05-10:44)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Runtime Error: c:/oocd7/bin-x64/../scripts/target/lpc3250.cfg:34: invalid command name "jtag"
in procedure 'script'
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 58
at file "c:/oocd7/bin-x64/../scripts/board\phytec_lpc3250.cfg", line 1
at file "c:/oocd7/bin-x64/../scripts/target/lpc3250.cfg", line 34
```

Devices that have been installed with "libusb-win32" drivers:

```
Olimex OpenOCD JTAG ARM-USB-OCD-H Interface 0 
Olimex OpenOCD JTAG ARM-USB-OCD-H Interface 1 
USB component Device
```

Very much thanks to any comments!

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of the files? It appears that you need to place the interface file before the board file. [http://elinux.org/OpenOCD_Troubleshooting:_Invalid_Command_Name_JTAG]

Comment: @Derek, That's correct. Can you put your comment into an answer?

Comment: Links to more jtag and debugging info: 
[Debugging kernel with jtag on embedded.com](http://www.embedded.com/design/operating-systems/4207333/Debugging-the-Linux-kernel-with-JTAG). 
[Debugging a tiny kernel with qemu on free-electrons](http://free-electrons.com/community/demos/qemu-arm-directfb/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place the interface file before the board file.

Instead of:

`> openocd -f board\phytec_lpc3250.cfg -f interface\olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h.cfg`

You want :

`> openocd -f interface\olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h.cfg -f board\phytec_lpc3250.cfg`

Source: http://elinux.org/OpenOCD_Troubleshooting:_Invalid_Command_Name_JTAG